# Regex to match CPE 2.3

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate CPE 2.3 names with a regular expression.
The basic structure of a CPE 2.3 name is as follows:

```
cpe:2.3:part:vendor:product:version:update:edition:lang:sw_edition:target_sw:target_hw:other
```

part, vendor, product, version etc.. can consist of a series of alphanumeric characters, digits and some special characters which are defined in the standard.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that it is allowed to use an escaped colon (\:) within either of these fields (vendor, product, etc..). Therefore I can't use a quantifier to check if the right amount of fields are present within a CPE.

[Example]

```
Regex = cpe\:2\.3\:[aho](\:[a-zA-Z0-9\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\_\.\/\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\\^\`\{\|\}\~]+)\g<1>{9}
```

Validating the following CPE Name with this regex works just fine:

```
cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.4.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

However, validating the following CPE name with the same regular expression fails since the quantifier is wrong due to the \: sequence in the product field of the CPE.

```
cpe:2.3:a:alawar:motor_town\\:_machine_soul_free:1.1:*:*:*:*:android:*:*
```

Another example where the matching fails is the following:

```
cpe:2.3:a:lemonldap-ng:lemonldap\\:\\::0.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

Here the matching still fails because of the \: sequence but for a different reason because now the + quantifier for the first capturing group is not satisfied.

How can I match such a CPE properly without using a greedy quantifier?

Comment: Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/fD3jC7/1) be satisfying?

Comment: No this would unfortunately not be satisfying since this regex allows for CPEs with more fields than allowed to be matched. Your example also allows to have blank fields like cpe:2.3:a::::::::etc

Comment: How about [now](https://regex101.com/r/fD3jC7/2) ?

Comment: No, this still allows for more fields than allowed to be matched. For example the CPE Name "cpe:2.3:a:vendor:product:version:update:edition:lang:sw_edition:target_sw:target_hw:other:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla" would be valid.

Comment: How many fields are allowed ? If i count correctly it's 10. See [update](https://regex101.com/r/fD3jC7/3)

Comment: Exactly 10 if you exclude the cpe:2.3:part section

Comment: Thank you very much @ThomasAyoub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should do the trick:

```
cpe:2\.3:[aho](?::(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\\\-_.\/;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~]|\\:)+){10}$
```

See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD3jC7/3)

---

This part is particularly interesting:

```
(?::(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,\\\-_.\/;<=>?@\[\]^`{|}~]|\\:)+)
```

Because it allow the input to be almost everything OR being `\:` inside the value.

Comment: This regex doesn't follow the WFN format. You can find the grammar definition (ABNF) in section 6.2.1 of official documentation [NISTIR 7695](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/nistir/7695/final).

Answer (score 11):

Official CPE schema specify this regex:

```
cpe:2\.3:[aho\*\-](:(((\?*|\*?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]|(\\[\\\*\?!"#$$%&'\(\)\+,/:;<=>@\[\]\^`\{\|}~]))+(\?*|\*?))|[\*\-])){5}(:(([a-zA-Z]{2,3}(-([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?)|[\*\-]))(:(((\?*|\*?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]|(\\[\\\*\?!"#$$%&'\(\)\+,/:;<=>@\[\]\^`\{\|}~]))+(\?*|\*?))|[\*\-])){4}
```

Reference: https://csrc.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-naming_2.3.xsd